# Extracting full filename on Windows/Linux/OSX

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to modify the following code:

```
 String[] sarr = (new String("a\\b\\c\\d.jar")).split("[(/)|(\\)]");
 System.out.println(sarr[sarr.length-1]);
```

so that the new string could be any path of a jar file on any system. With perl regex I would do it easily, but with Java regex I don't get the desired results. How can I accomplish that? I need to get d.jar.

I saw many diffeerent posts, but they all were specific and not general or not like what I need.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use `File.getAbsolutePath()` ?

Comment: I'm modifying code I wrote 2 years ago, so I don't remember why :). BTW I'm not a serial killer but I know where I live ;). Checking it right now.

Comment: "I don't get the desired results" - what results _do_ you get?

Comment: Nope, it's not what I need. It gives me C:\Users\vitali\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Test\a\b\c\d.jar and I need d.jar

Comment: @VitaliPom, then use `File.getName()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java string literal `"[(/)|(\\)]"` represents the regular expression `[(/)|(\)]`, which is a character class which will match any single `(`, `/`, `|` or `)` character.  Instead you probably want the regular expression `[/\\]` (matching a single forward or backward slash), which in turn means `"[/\\\\]"` as a Java string literal.

```
str.split("[/\\\\]");
```

Alternatively if you know you'll always be dealing with paths that are native to the system you're running on at the time (i.e. `C:\Users\something` when running on Windows and `/home/user` when running on Linux/Mac/etc.) then you can use the `java.io.File` class:

```
File f = new File(fullPath);
String name = f.getName();
```

`getName()` returns just the last name component, there's also `getPath()` which returns the full path string stored in the `File` object (which may be a relative path) and `getAbsolutePath()` which returns the absolute path (the same as `getPath()` if this is already absolute, or `getPath()` prefixed with the current working directory if it is relative).

But if you might be dealing with Windows paths on a Unix-like system or vice versa then you'll have to stick with doing your own string manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using regular expressions, or any other string parsing mechanism, use `java.io.File`. It provides many methods, to obtain the name of the file use `File.getName()`:

```
String file_name = new File("a\\b\\c\\d.jar").getName();
System.out.println(file_name);
```

Output:

> d.jar